# MariaDB Galera cluster: are replicate-do-db filters applied before or after data sent?

Tags: mariadb, galera

I would like to synchronize only some databases on a cluster, with `replicate-do-db`.

→ If I use the Galera cluster, are all data sent over the network, or are nodes smart enough to only fetch their specific databases?

On "classic" master/slave MariaDB replication, filters are made by the **slave**, causing network charge for nothing if you don't replicate that database. You have to configure a [blackhole proxy](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/blackhole/) to filter binary logs to avoid this ([setup example](http://jroller.com/dschneller/entry/mysql_replication_using_blackhole_engine)), but the administration after is not really easy. So it would be perfect with a cluster if I can perform the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

`binlog_...` are performed in the sending (Master) node.

`replicate_...` are performed in the receiving (Slave) node.

Is this filtered server part of the cluster?  If so, you are destroying much of the beauty of Galera.

On the other hand, if this is a Slave hanging off one of the Galera nodes and the Slave does not participate in the "cluster", this is a reasonable architecture.

Comment: Thanks! For the filter, it is because I want to create an extranet server in our DMZ... and I don't want all corporate data go in it, only those needed by customers :)